# Service worker does not cache index.html served by golang server on '/'

Tags: javascript, go, service, worker

I'm playing around with a service worker trying to cache my index.html. I'm serving it via

```
http.HandleFunc("/sw", handle.SW)
http.HandleFunc("/", handle.Index)
```

My service worker cache looks like this

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    self.skipWaiting();
    event.waitUntil(async function () {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_VERSION);
        await cache.addAll([
            '/',
            '/static/merged.css',
            '/static/merged.js',
            '/favicon.ico'
        ]);
    }());
});
```

Without the service worker my network tab in the developer tools shows the size of the index.html with 4.5 KB and a time of 46ms.

[image]

Now with the service worker merged.css, merged.js and favicon.ico are cached, but my index has two entries. One from service worker, and one of size 4.5 KB and a time of 48ms.

[image]

So I'm guessing that index.html is not cached and I can not find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you uploaded, it says that the request for fetching the index.html is initiated by a script named sw.js, and the exact code is placed at the second line. If this is truly the service-worker in your code, please recheck it carefully and find out why this request is made.

Comment: I think that's how it should work. The service worker requests the resources, if they are not cached yet. If I deactivate the cache, all resource fetchings are initiated by sw.js.

Comment: Nevermind, I had service worker update on reload activated. It works as intended. Thank you.

Comment: The weired thing is the request still be made although the cache is there.  May be it's possible to find the exact reason from the full sw.js if you are ok to paste it here.